# Test if two survival curves are different in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I have generated two survival curves (Kaplan-Meier estimate) using the function `survfit` for R from the `survival` packagem, with a survival object of the form `Surv(time_1, time_2, event)` and the formula `Surv(time_1, time_2, event) ~ gender`.

I would like to perform a statistical test of equality of the two resulting survival curves.

Unfortunately such a form of survival object is not admissible for `survdiff`. It only accepts `Surv(time_2, event)` which gives different (and in my case wrong) results.

Is there a function which allows me to compare the two curves based on the results of `survfit`?

Here is the code to create sample data:

```
e<-c(1, 0 ,1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
t1<-c(35, 35, 34, 35, 35, 35, 34, 35, 35, 35, 34, 35, 35, 35, 34, 35)
t2<-c(36, 37, 37, 36, 36,37, 35, 36, 36, 37, 37, 36, 36, 37, 35, 36)
g<-c("F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M")
data<-cbind(g,t1,t2,e)
data<-data.frame(data)
#result differs
km<-survfit(Surv(time_1,time_2,event)~Gender,data=data_test)
km2<-survfit(Surv(time_2,event)~Gender,data=data_test)
```

Comment: Data? Data? Data?

Comment: Í added R-code to generate data to my post.

Comment: Using bind coerces those numeric values to character and then there is a complete mismatch of variable names.

Answer (score 0):

From what I got reading up a bit on the subject, the usual logrank test is not defined for interval censored data. This explains why the `survdiff` function is complaining about right-censored data.

Nonetheless, there exists generalizations of the logrank for interval censored data. Some seems to be implemented in the `interval` package ([described here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4184046/)).

I cannot really help you more as I only work with right censored data so I never needed these generalization.

I hope that this can help you anyway.